# display the filenames from a directory in separate table rows in html/php

Tags: php, css, arrays, foreach, html-table

I am working on a php code as shown below in which I want to display the file names in separate table rows in php.

```
$destination = 'outgoing_folder';    
$mp3_files = scandir($destination); /* Line #A */
print_r($mp3_files);                /* Line #B */
```

**Line#B print the following o/p:**

```
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => 36017P.mp3 [3] => 36031P.mp3 [4] => hello.mp3 )
```

The HTML/PHP code which I have used in order to display the content in table is:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <!-- This inline css will go inside addiional css -->    
        <th style="width=8%;" >House#</th>
        <th style="width=8%;">MP3</th>
        <th style="width=8%;" >Program Name</th>
        <th style="width=4%;">Title</th>
        <th style="width=8%;" >Description</th>
        <th style="width=8%;" >Program Name</th>
        <th style="width=4%;" >Title</th>
        <th style="width=8%;">Description</th>
    </tr>
<tr>
       <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;"><?php echo $mp4_files[2];?></td>
       <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;"><?php echo $mp3_files[2];?></td>             /* Line Z */
       <td style="width:8%;"><?php echo $path_program_en[0]->value; ?> </td>
       <td style="width:8%;"><?php echo $path_title_en[0]->value; ?></td>
       <td style="width:8%;"><?php echo $path_description_en[0]->value; ?></td>
       <td style="width:8%;"><?php echo $path_program_fr[0]->value; ?> </td>
       <td style="width:8%;"><?php echo $path_title_fr[0]->value; ?></td>
       <td style="width:8%;"><?php echo $path_description_fr[0]->value; ?></td>
</tr>
```

I have used Line #A at Line#Z to print *2nd file name from a directory* in a separate table rows in php.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to add at Line#Z (present in the HTML code) so that it print all the file names **(36017P.mp3 36031P.mp3 hello.mp3)**  in separate rows in html.

Comment: You need a `foreach` to go through that array and output each element of the array.

Comment: I tried with something like this 

`<?php foreach (array_diff(scandir($audio_mp3), array('..', '.')) as $file) : ?> <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;"><?php echo $file;?></td> <?php endforeach ?>` but its not printing in separate rows..

Comment: `<td>` is a column within a row `<tr>`. You would need to start a new row before outputting the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$mp3_files` is an array, you need to iterate on it.

To do so, you can use [for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) or [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statments.

If you whan to display ALL files in the same TD but on a new line though, you can use the [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function with `<br>` as the glue (it should do the trick):

```
<?php echo implode('<br>', $mp3_files); ?>
```

Or use `foreach` to display it as a list:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($mp3_files as $file) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $file; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

If you whan to display EACH file on a new TR, then you will have to use `for` or `foreach` (as shown by @Declan) :

```
<?php foreach($mp3_files as $file) : ?>
<tr>
    <!-- other tds here -->
    <td><?php echo $file; ?></td>
    <!-- other tds here -->
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But if I'm correctly understand your code, this approach will force you to repeat all other tds datas on each new row (tr).

Comment: I have modified my question. If I want to print mp4_files in separate rows. Should I be doing something like this `<?php foreach($mp3_files, $mp4_files as $file, $file2) : ?>
<tr>
    <!-- other tds here -->
    <td><?php echo $file; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $file2; ?></td>
    <!-- other tds here -->
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: There are some other td elements which have multiple values. I am not sure in that case how it will work.

Comment: I have applied your logic and its working perfectly fine. Thanks for that.

Comment: Sorry I was offline. I'm glad I was able to help you.

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430459/how-to-convert-mp4-files-into-mp3-on-button-click-using-ffmpeg-php). Its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you will need to loop through each item in the array using a foreach and output them into separate rows for example:

```
    foreach ($mp3_files as $key => $value) { ?>
      <tr><td><?php echo $value; ?></td></tr>
     <?php
     }
?>
```

Something to keep in mind is that the `<tr>` tags are the table rows, so to have the data separated by rows you will need output them into different `<tr>` tags each time, also don't forget to use the `<td>` tags inside the rows to ensure the table recognises it as table data.